# ClassNotFoundException When running jar file but runs fine in Intellij

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

I created a small mqtt application using [eclipse paho mqtt library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) in kotlin with Gradle in Intellij IDE. it runs fine when running it through Intellij but when I build it and run the jar file that gets created I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` error.

From other questions I have seen about this it looks like it has something to do with the class path but I am not sure what needs to be done if that is indeed the issue because I am using gradle and not jar files for libraries.

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html?section=Gradle%20Groovy#c077ffa0)

Here is my gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.31'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'me.package'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.publisher.MainKt'
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.publisher.MainKt'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

And my MainKt file

```
package com.publisher

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence
import java.io.File

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val client = MqttClient("tcp://192.168.0.55:1883","publisher", MemoryPersistence())
    val connOpts = MqttConnectOptions()
    connOpts.isCleanSession = false
    connOpts.isAutomaticReconnect = true

    client.setCallback(object: MqttCallback {

        override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable?) {
            println("Connection lost")
            println(cause!!.message)
        }

        override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
            println("Message Received for topic: $topic")
            println("Message: ${message!!.payload}")
        }

        override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken?) {
            println("Message delivered")
        }

    })
    try{
        client.connect(connOpts)
        println("Connected")
        client.subscribe("config/+", 1) { topic, message ->
            println("Getting configuration for $message")
            val path = System.getProperty("user.dir")
            val file = File("$path/${message}.json")
            if(file.exists()){
                client.publish("/devices/ + $message + /config", MqttMessage(file.readBytes()))
            }
        }
    }catch (e: MqttException){
        println("Error: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably give gradle‘s application plugin a try, to build an application bundle with the needed libraries included.

Comment: @dpr In the tutorial I was following (I linked it above since I forgot to mention it) didn't say anything about that. I did quickly glance at the documentation for the plugin but I didnt immediately see anything about including other dependencies/libraries

Comment: what is the content of the jar file? you can open it with any zip tool like 7zip or unzip on the command line. How are you starting your application? with java -jar <buildJar>?

Comment: @JensBaitinger the jar file contains `MainKt$main$1.class`, `MainKt$main$2.class` and `MainKt.class` files along with a `META_INF` folder with manifest and a `.kotlin_module` file. Currently I am just running the jar file by right clicking on the file in intellij and selecting run but the same thing happens when doing `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: is the MainKt in the correct folder (according to its package) or is it in the root?

Comment: @JensBaitinger All the .class files are in the `com/publisher` folder structure not in the root

Comment: whats the content of the manifest? does it refer the com.publisher.MainKt? and which class is refered in the NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: @JensBaitinger yes this is what it contains `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.publisher.MainKt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you start your application does not include the dependencies, meaning your MQTT driver and the Kotlin dependencies are not included.

Do the following:

```
gradle distZip
# alternatively
gradle distTar
```

This will create a zip/tar file containing all the dependencies and a start script. Use that to start your application.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong folder, in the distributions folder I now see a .zip file with all the kotlin and paho libs. When I extract the zip file and run the `bat` file it works

Comment: The ultimate goal is to run this on a raspberry pi will I still be able to do this?

Comment: as long as you have a JRE with the right verstion installed, there is everything in that zip you need to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the [Shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) plugin, as it is straightforward to use. Your `build.gradle` would look something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.31'
    
    // Shadow plugin
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'me.package'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.publisher.MainKt'
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.publisher.MainKt'
    }
}
```

So your fat JAR is generated in the `/build/libs` directory with all the dependencies included.